# Why is MySQLSlap giving me additional prompt instead of running?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to benchmark some queries using mysqlslap.  I've never used it before.  I am trying to follow some tutorials and am trying to run a simple command to get a hang of how it works like from [this](https://tosbourn.com/mysqlslap-a-quickstart-guide/) tutorial.

When I run the command `mysqlslap --concurrency=20 --iterations=4 --query="sELCT * FROM listusers;" --create-schema=my_database` instead of actually testing and returning some metrics, I just get another prompt like

[image: this]

I have tried this command with username and password fields as well with the same results.

What is this prompt and how do I get the command to actually run the metrics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqlslap` is not a MySQL command, but a separate binary tool.

So instead of trying to use it inside mysql console, use it directly in bash/shell.

Comment: That was it, I'm using Windows Server 2012 so I had to use Powerhsell, move to the directory, and also I had to use the command `.\mysqlslap` to indicate I trusted it as it would not run `mysqlslap`.  Thanks!